# Tracking stock prices and email alerts

Tags: triggers, google-apps-script

I have a google spreadsheet which helps us to **track some stocks prices** from the NASDAQ and DOWJONES. When I open the spreadsheet the prices automatically refresh via google finance built-in functions.

That is, for instance, the Apple price in a certain cell:

```
=GoogleFinance("AAPL";"price")
```

So far so good. Now we have a target buying price for each value and when the price falls below our target price we get an alert. I have written a script so that when this happens it sends me an email notification. Moreover, I have also configured a time-driven trigger which executes the script every 5 minutes.

But WHAT I really need is the WHOLE spreadsheet to open every 5 minutes not just only the script so that the Google finance funcions load and get the updated stock prices.

Is there a way to do that?

Not sure if this is the best approaching for a stock tracking spreadsheet so any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A standalone script will open a spreadsheet but it does not wait for the functions like GoogleFinance to complete so you may need to put in an explicit wait or loop until complete